# How to and from where install ClockworkMod Recovery (CWM) on GT-P1000?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-tab, clockworkmod-recovery, bootloader, rom-manager

Currently I am trying to upgrade my Android OS from 2.3.3 to Cyanogenmod 9 not with "Odin" but via the bootloader and SD-card. Now I had a problem with "Signature verification failed" [described here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1483840) which is highly likely due to the fact that I failed to install a custom bootloader. Now as it is mentioned everywhere **as a pre-requisite**, I want to install "ClockworkMod Recovery", but I cannot find it anywhere! More so in articles around the www from bloggers and journalists (who actually never tried what they wrote about) it is assumed that you already have installed CWM. It seems to be needed also for other ROM's for the **EU Samsung Galaxy Tab 7"inch (GT-P1000)**, not only the one that I want to install.

The actual problem is:

When I try to install CWM **with ROM Manager** (5.0.0.6) **it *only* shows** the **two** models "Samsung Epic4G" and "Samsung GalaxyS i9000" in the list and not my model (Galaxy Tab EU) or any other model.

When I researched I only found **outdated** YouTube videos and XDA-developer threads that don't provide a link to a newer / the most current solution. Most of all, **I had a hard time coming up with *any* Google search results that provide a *current* solution** for my issue.

I am willing to try anything to get CWM up and running, as long as the process is outlined somewhere more or less understandable.

Finally: I am aware that I void the warranty I never had. I did win my Galaxy Tab, thus never paid for it and never got a receipt and now live in another country anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot install CWM recovery onto the Samsung Galaxy Tab P1000 via ROM Manager app.  You will need to flash it via Odin or Heimdal utilities.

XDA-Developers forums are a good start.  I suggest reading up on the [Galaxy Tab Android Development](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=807) section.  [This thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=924654) seems to have good instructions for flashing ClockWorkMod v3 along with a Euro-specific kernel.  This should be a good start that will allow you to format the Tab to Ext4 file system, and allow for flashing other ROMs such as CM9 alpha/beta.

> What's in the package:
>
> - Galaxy TAB (euro) kernel
> - 1.4Ghz clockspeed (stock voltage)
> - Voodoo Sound patch V6 (search the market for the Voodoo Control App)
> - 100 % MCR EXT4 compatible & separate Overcome version
> - UV control by sysfs or app (thanks to xan)
> - Camera/key-backlight working
> - UV LCD (3.3v to 2.6v) thanks to koxudaxi
> - UV RAM(1.8v to 1.6v) thanks to koxudaxi
> - LED Flash for flash light apps thanks to koxudaxi
> - Filesystem support - EXT2/EXT3/EXT4
> - frequencies 100/200/400/800/1000/1200/1400
> - rooted adb shell
> - ClockworkMod 3 (thanks to Paul Obrien)
>
> Always BACKUP your stuff before flashing anything.
>
> Extract the zip and use Heimdall to flash the zImage (kernel directory).
>   Heimdall must be version 1.1.0 or greater.
>   You MUST have the libusb drivers WORKING in download mode before you can flash using
>   Heimdall.
>
> Use the command line:
>   `heimdall flash --kernel zImage`
>   where zImage is the name of the kernel, full path names are allowed.
>
> Downloadlink:
>
> [Galaxy Tab 1.4Ghz V16 - MCR version](http://xda.richardtrip.org/tab/GalaxyTab_1400_MCR_ext_V16.zip)
>
> If you have a problem with the sensors just push this file to
>   /system/lib/hw: http://xda.richardtrip.org/tab/sensors.default.so

Comment: Thanks man, I actually flashed - indeed with Odin - to Overcome 4.0! (Not 4.1, I think, I just went by the tutorial.) I then overwrote this one with the CM 9 ROM and kernel...

Comment: That's disappointing to hear. I'm currently halfway through this tutorial which links to ROM Manager with explicit instruction to use it to flash ClockWorkMod Recovery onto a GT P1000. http://www.mobiada.com/how-to-install-cyanogenmod-10-1-on-samsung-galaxy-tab-gt-p1000/   Is the article bogus?